# Find char which appears maximal number of times

Tags: c#, interview-questions

I had 15 minutes to code the following question:

Given a file name return the char which appears maximal number of times.

please do not take into account the unit test.
Please look at the final foreach loop, I could have also used a for loop, I have doubts what is the best way to implement finding a max value and get the key from the dictionary.

Also please comment about code style.
Thanks

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{

    [TestClass]
    public class GetMostRepeatedCharQuestion
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestForAasMax()
        {
            char result = GetMaxCharHelper.GetMaxReaptedCharFromFile("MaxA.txt");
            Assert.AreEqual('A', result);
        }
    }

    public class GetMaxCharHelper
    {
        public static char GetMaxReaptedCharFromFile(string fileName)
        {
            Dictionary<char, int> charToCount = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();
                    foreach (var currentChar in charArray)
                    {
                        if (charToCount.ContainsKey(currentChar))
                        {
                            charToCount[currentChar]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            charToCount.Add(currentChar, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    //don't forget to get next line when reading from a file
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                }

                int maxCount = 0;
                char maxChar = '\0';
                foreach (var current in charToCount)
                {
                    if (current.Value > maxCount)
                    {
                        maxCount = current.Value;
                        maxChar = current.Key;
                    }
                }
                return maxChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming modern C#, there are a couple of things you could do to be more concise:

1. Instead of the dance with `while((line = reader.NextLine())...)` you can just use [`File.ReadLines`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) and `foreach` over that.
2. You can declare variables inside the `TryGetValue` like so: `charToCount.TryGetValue(currentChar, out int count)` where you can use `count` afterwards without having to declare it on its own line.
3. While keeping score of your most seen `char` inside the loop is certainly more efficient (as @pattpass did in their answer), you could also extract the character with the highest count at the end with a still readable oneliner:

   ```
   return charToCount.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.Value).First().Key;
   ```
4. What's completely absent in your method is error handling. What happens if the file does not exist or you aren't allowed to access it? It seems like you handle empty files with returning `\0` and `0`. It is debatable if that's what one would expect.

All in all, your code could look somewhat likes this:

```
static char GetMostRepeatedChar(string filename)
{
    // you could also not handle this case here and delegate
    // that responsibility to the caller
    if(!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        return '\0';
    }

    var charCount = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        foreach (var c in line)
        {
            charCount.TryGetValue(c, out int count);
            charCount[c] = count + 1;
        }
    }

    if (charCount.Count == 0)
    {
        // this is debatable and depends on the real use case
        // in production code you should never throw a raw 'Exception'
        // but rather something more specific
        throw new Exception("empty file"); 
    }

    return charCount.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.Value).First().Key;
}
```

Comment: I think that is is fine to throw an exception if file if not found. I think that's what most developers would expect when working with `IO`. Otherwise I like your suggestions, good refactoring.

Comment: Germi i did check for file exists however the interviewer said. Why did you check only if file exists? What about file locked. Or havinf no permissions and so on all in all I think stream reader can throw better exceptions and i need to try catch them later on and log them or show error to the user

Answer (score 11):

According to a modern C# and LINQ you could try to "shock" interviewer with solving in a row:

```
var res = File.ReadAllText(path)
            .Where(ch => char.IsLetter(ch))
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .First()
            .Key;
```

Comment: Finally! I was already going to cry because nobody have posted it yet ;-) Additionally instead of sorting it you could just use `.Max()`

Comment: Oh, no, you cannot, sorry, my bad - you want the key not the count ;-]

Comment: You should probably use `File.ReadLines` instead. Not that it matters much, since `GroupBy` will load the entire file into memory either way. Still , no reason to load it *twice*. This attempt to shock the interviewer can easily backfire, if you can't explain the implications of using LINQ very well during the interview. :)